# How to pipe Watson speech using the Text-to-Speech service to the browser

Tags: ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I have an express application and I added this snippet of code:

```
var TextToSpeechV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech/v1');
var fs = require('fs');

var text_to_speech = new TextToSpeechV1({
  username: '<username>', (added username and password)
  password: '<password>'
});

var params = {
  text: 'Hello from IBM Watson',
  voice: 'en-US_AllisonVoice', // Optional voice
  accept: 'audio/wav'
};

// Pipe the synthesized text to a file
text_to_speech.synthesize(params).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.wav'));
```

After running the `node app` command, a `ouput.wav` was generated in my file. It worked as expected and said "Hello from IBM Watson." But I want this to be outputted to the browser, like when someone presses a  tag. How do I go from here?

Comment: stuff the .wav into your site's document root somewhere, and then simply point a client-side `<audio>` tag at it?

Comment: what would the properties of the <audio> tag be?

Answer (score 0):

The Text to Speech [demo](https://text-to-speech-demo.mybluemix.net/) does what you want and it's on [GitHub](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech-nodejs). It streams the audio back to the Browser which uses an `<audio>` HTML tag to reproduce it.

If yo useparate your application in Client and Server you will need:

#### Client

An `<audio>` element with the `src` pointing to an endpoint that synthesizes the text, something like: `https://<host>/api/synthesize?text=This+is+a+test`

#### Server

> Assuming you use Express and based on your code above

```
app.get('/api/synthesize', function(req, res, next) {
  var transcript = text_to_speech.synthesize(req.query);
  transcript.on('error', next);
  transcript.pipe(res);
});
```

The audio will be pipe to the browser which will play it as it comes from the service.